# SaaS platform and client footer links

Tags: seo, saas

I have a SaaS platform where people can create their own white labeled job boards.

My main product domain is www.myproductdomain.com

When clients sign up they automatically get clientname.myproductdomain.com. They can also choose to use a custom domain by setting up a CNAME.

At the bottom of every white labeled site is a link back to my main site "Powered by My Product Name".  Should I consider making these nofollow links?

I have around 1600 clients using the product at the moment.

Comment: Also many other questions and answers regarding site wide links http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Footer+links+is%3Aquestion

Comment: You may find http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44829/how-do-thousands-of-backlinks-to-my-subdomains-affect-seo/44832#44832 also useful too. Google treats sub domains as any other domain using `www.`.

Comment: **Actually, this is a really bad idea!!** I fully explain how and why in this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59290/do-created-by-links-add-values-to-my-website/69808#69808